# JQuery, Loading images in sequence

Tags: jquery, image, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox, Masonry and Infinite-scroll in my photo blog.
Everything works fine, but I would like to make it work better...

I load a list of thumbnails which link to some hidden div that contains the bigger image I show with colorbox.
Something like this:

```
<a href="colorbox"><img thumbnail></a>
<hidden div><img bigger image></div>
```

All the thumbnail are sorted by Masonry, the problem is that I have to load all the bigger images before masonry can sort the thumbnails!
Is there any way to load the bigger images only after the colorbox call?

The website is this: http://www.photocracy.eu/

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear to me. First, isn't this a Masonry issue - him having to wait to sort?  OK, perhaps not. If the question is "is there a way to display a fullsize image with ColorBox without first loading it into the page", then you should investigate acquiring the image content via AJAX. Otherwise, Colorbox pretty much expects the images to be in the page prior to it being called.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in this way:
I generate html of the page with `<img rel="url">` instead of `<img src="url">`. When I have to load the big image, i replace the src with the rel argument.
In this way the browser doesn't load all the images, but only the ones I want to load.